# how to use HttpsUrlConnection in java

Tags: java, authentication, curl, https

I have a command line:

```
curl -u username:passwd -k "https://myserver/a/b/c"
```

It works and I will get right information when I call it under Ubuntu or Cygwin.

Now I am willing to accomplish it in Java. So I have Java code like that:

```
    public class Test {

    public static String auth = "username:passwd";
    public static String url = "https:/myserver/a/b/c";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url);
            final byte[] authBytes = auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String encoding = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authBytes);
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encoding);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But It seems not work and always return HTTP response code 411.
Is there something wrong with the java code?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You're doing a POST but not sending anything. Is that what `curl` does? Otherwise you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: The curl command makes a GET...

Answer (score 1):

HTTP response code 411 means that "The server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content- Length."

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

`HttpsUrlConnection` should be able to do that for you.  Check out `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()`.  I think you will also need to `setDoOutput()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am willing to add `setDoOutput(true)` and `setFixedLengthStreamingMode (int contentLength)` . But I don't know hot to set parameter `contentLength`. I gave it some random values and just got `IOException: insufficient data written`. I also tired  `setChunkedStreamingMode`, but still cannot work.

Comment: You have to set it to the length of the data you write, which is zero.